# The difference between PhoneGap and Titanium4j Mobile

Tags: android, iphone, gwt, cordova

For iOS and Android application development based on GWT, I'm confronted with two choices:

- Cordova / PhoneGap + mgwt
- Titanuim4j Mobile + Touch4j

Has anybody successfully integrated one or both of them? Do you know what are the pros and cons ?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

For one: Touch4j does not support Firefox, so if you are developing with GWT in Windows, you cannot view your application in dev mode (there's no GWT plugin for Safari or Chrome  for Windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question for your second bullet should really be about the difference between Titanium and Touch, and your decision can boil down to which underlying technology you'd like to use based on your requirements.  From 10,000 feet, the Titanium framework will translate as much as it possibly can to native, whereas Touch is strictly an HTML5 framework that runs--as others have already mentioned--in the device's webview.

Now, from the perspective of Emitrom's products:

Titanium4j - is a Java binding for the Titanium framework.  You will use GWT simply as the compiler that takes your Java to Javascript, and then that Javascript is further translated by the Titanium framework.  When using Titanium4j, you have access to the hardware via the underlying Titanium framework.

Touch4j - is a Java binding for the Touch framework.  Additionally, it does contain a package for Cordova, so you can also have access to the hardware.  The GWT compiler is used to take all that Java to Javascript, and thanks to Cordova it all runs in the device's webview.  Touch4j has already been hailed by some as the "best GWT mobile framework" out there.  See http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228405-GXT-Mobile

Here are 2 tutorials for deploying Touch4j apps to iOS and Android:

http://emitrom.com/touch4j/tutorials/hello-ios

http://emitrom.com/touch4j/tutorials/hello-android

Chrome does have a GWT plugin for Windows (and Mac for that matter), so you should be able to use that to develop in either Titanium4j or Touch4j.  The key to the latter being that it is webkit-based, and hence it doesn't work on Firefox.

I can also give you a bit of pros and cons on Titanium4j and Touch4j:

Debugging in Titanium4j is more difficult than with Touch4j, which fully supports it.  Also, if you are looking for a widget library that is ready to go, stick to Touch4j.

And now, like the Oracle once said, something that "will bake your noodle":  Emitrom is getting ready to release the Lienzo framework.  Lienzo is a 100% Java implementation of canvas, where you'll basically have control of every aspect of your user interface.  Think of animations, transformations, dragging, images, video, audio... in short, Lienzo will give you the ability to do everything you can do in canvas with Javascript, but using Java.  Pair this with our Cordova binding, and now you can push canvas-based apps to mobile devices.  Long gone will be the days where non-webkit-based browsers are out of luck: now every browser that adheres to the HTML5 spec (which includes canvas), can use Lienzo, be it on the device, on the browser, or on the desktop (via some other technology like Air4j).

In any case, you are the first to hear about Lienzo :-)  Think of it as the foundation for rich UI libraries, games, apps, etc., all in Java using canvas underneath the covers.  Lienzo will be free and open source.  We are really excited and hope to push a beta before the month is over.  Not every feature mentioned above will be included in the first release, so our roadmap is rich with things to do.

Full disclosure: I'm one of the co-founders of Emitrom.

Best of luck!

Comment: The Lienzo framework is in alpha as of November 1st.  http://www.dzone.com/links/javas_future_lays_in_lienzo.html  Get it today!

Answer (score 4):

phonegap and Titanium have completely different ways, phonegap in onehand is using webview component for displaying your html-javascript code and also create a bridge between your code and native code on the other hand Titanium compile your javascript code to native code and has nothing to do with webview or html5.

some main differences that those approches cause are :

1. phonegao has many performance issues because it render html code at runtime.
2. unlike Titanium phonegap can benefit from full power of html5 and javascript in contrast Titanium is limited in that aspect 
   .
   3.phonegap support wider rang of devices.
   ...

Comment: sorry for unaccepting but the other answer was more elaborate ! I would accept both if i could (no need for revenge :))

Answer (score 2):

There is a GWT DevMode for Chrome on Windows.

Note that you can also use Touch4j with PhoneGap. 
Touch4j has a "Device" module that wraps the PhoneGap(Cordova) API.